# Image doesn't load using glide

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I am using glide for image loading but I don't know what's problem with my glide

I add image for reference. ➡️ [Glide Error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFmZsy86pb9kvgwsx6H3JlIWJ7Amd2gG/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to fetch images from url.

My Code :-

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(path)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .into(imageView)
```

Comment: does this path ----> " https://198.211.99.129/laundry/public/images/categories/images/1672300041221229.png " exist on live server ?  or locally ? the problems seems to be, Glide is refused to connect to the server.

Comment: Its exist on live server.

Comment: make sure your internet connection works well.

Comment: my internet connection is good.